# How to get Azure ACS refresh token

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, azure, oauth-2.0, acs

We are developing a SOA application which uses Azure & ACS as server side components and iPhone & Windows Phone as clients. We were able to establish the authentication scenarios successfully as per the sample available in code plex.

http://acs.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ACS%20Windows%20Phone%20Sample

ie using passive authentication with Windows Phone Push notification.

Now we are experiencing the authentication token time out which we would like to resolve by adopting the refresh token method. But we didn't find any method to obtain the refresh token while we authenticate first time. ie its not available in the ScriptNotify event of Windows Phone's browser.

Can somebody help to resolve the scenario using refresh_token? Or are there any other method which is better than refresh_token ?

Joy

According to MSFT its not possible to refresh_token in windows phone 7 scenario.Users must login again.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuresecurity/thread/aaa21f8d-f2bb-4aa1-b7a2-6745c4c9591c

Answer (score 1):

When using SWT Tokens, it's not possible to get a refresh token. Refresh tokens are an OAuth 2.0 feature.

Comment: SWT can be used as an access token with OAuth2, and therefore can be used in conjunction with refresh tokens. It's true however that an SWT by nature does not describe a refresh token.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of getting Refresh Token and then Access Token with oAuth2 and consuming in the application:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adventurousidentity/archive/2011/09/18/acs-v2-oauth-2-0-delegation-support-explained.aspx

Comment: It's not for the faint hearted. ACS only provides one half of the required endpoint for OAuth2 and requires a degree of integration and magic to build a full OAuth2 solution. It's easier if you just use their UI for login, but not always preferable.